# Selenium + Python3.x как переключить поиск элемента на новое открытое окно

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

С помощью selenium нажимаю на кнопку и у меня открывается новое окно как мне в новом окне найти нужный мне элемент. Тоесть я имею ввиду как переключить поиск элементов на открывшиеся окно а потом закрыть открывшиеся окно и перейти обратно на окно с которого все начиналось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для переключения нужно:

- Метод `driver.switch_to.window`, позволит переключаться
- Поле `driver.window_handles`, позволит получить список наименований окон

[Накидал пример открытия, переключения и загрузки:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/48f2b747bda410b9387f1be5175120fc07aec6f3/selenium__examples/switch_windows.py#L26)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

try:
    driver.get('https://yahoo.com')
    print(f'Title: "{driver.title}"')

    # Opens a new tab
    driver.execute_script("window.open()")
    driver.execute_script("window.open()")

    print('Tabs:', len(driver.window_handles), driver.window_handles)

    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.get('https://google.com')
    print(f'Switch to title: "{driver.title}"')

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
    driver.get('https://ya.ru')
    print(f'Switch to title: "{driver.title}"')

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    print(f'Switch to title: "{driver.title}"')

    time.sleep(2)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```